# Angular.js / Ionic make Tab-Button only clickable if var is set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

how is it possible to not let the user click on the tab-bar, before a scope variable is set. The first view in my app is a view, where you can choose your city. The other Tabs (which uses the value of "city") should only be clickable after the user selects that city. The city is stored in $rootScope.selectedCity and this is the state where the city is needed:

```
.state('tab.friends', {
      url: '/friends/:selectedCity',
      views: {
        'tab-friends': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-friends.html',
          controller: 'FriendsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

Any suggestions for only making the tabs clickable after the user selects the city? Ty

Comment: why you dont want to add `return;` in click method if it still doesn't exist?

Comment: The click method for the tab-bar is in the ionic library. Don´t want to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle `ion-tab` click by using `on-select` attribute, see : [DOCS](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTab/)

> on-select
>   (optional) |
>   expression
>   Called when this tab is selected.

In addition `ion-tab` supports `ng-click` as well: See [$ionicTabsDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicTabsDelegate/) usage